# Setting PDF document title and author with EVOPDF in a PDF/A-1b compliant file

Tags: c#, properties, metadata, document, evopdf

I'm trying to set some attributes on a HTML -> PDF generated file using EVOPDF.

It seems pretty straightforward to set the PdfDocumentInfo properties. As given by the documentation: http://www.evopdf.com/help/azure-html-to-pdf/html/T_EvoPdf_HtmlToPdfClient_PdfDocumentInfo.htm

However, Adobe Acrobat Reader shows empty boxes when viewing File->Properties. And a Hex editor doesn't find any of the data either.

I tried the "EvoHtmlToPdfDemo_VS2013" v6.4 solution which I downloaded from here  http://www.evopdf.com/download.aspx but PdfDocumentInfo isn't found in the entire solution. So no demo code to show how document properties should be set.

See my code below

```
  var converter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
        converter.ConversionDelay = 0;
        converter.ClipHtmlView = false;

        var paperSize = PaperSizeToSizeF(pPaperSize);
        var pdfPageOrientation = (pIsLandscape) ? PdfPageOrientation.Landscape : PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
        converter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = pdfPageOrientation;
        converter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfStandardSubset = PdfStandardSubset.Pdf_A_1b;

        //IMPORTANT FOR COMPLIANCE
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.AuthorName = "Mike de Klerk";
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.Title = "PDF/A-1b Test";
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.Subject = "Testing generation of PDF/A-1b compliant file by EVOPDF library.";
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.Keywords = "HTML, PDF, Converter, PDF/A-1b. compliance";
        converter.PdfDocumentInfo.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

**EDIT**:

When using the `EvoPdf.Document` object I can get it done. But I can't get it done using the `EvoPdf.HtmlToPdfConverter` object. I prefer to use the latter object though, because most of the documentation refers to the `HtmlToPdfConverter`. See the code below for the usage of `EvoPdf.Document` object.

```
        // Create the PDF document where to add the HTML documents
        var pdfDocument = new Document();

        // Set license key received after purchase to use the converter in licensed mode
        // Leave it not set to use the converter in demo mode
        pdfDocument.LicenseKey = LicenseKey;
        pdfDocument.DocumentInformation.Author = "Mike de Klerk";
        pdfDocument.DocumentInformation.Title = "PDF/A-1b Test";
        pdfDocument.DocumentInformation.Subject = "Testing generation of PDF/A-1b compliant file by EVOPDF library.";
        pdfDocument.DocumentInformation.Keywords = "HTML, PDF, Converter, PDF/A-1b. compliance";
        pdfDocument.DocumentInformation.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
```

**EDIT 2:**

There is a `HtmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.DocumentObject.DocumentInformation` object. But the `DocumentObject` is null before conversion. The documentation says

> A reference to the internal Document object initialized by converter during conversion

`DocumentObject` exists indeed after conversion, and I can confirm that the `DocumentInformation` properties aren't set after conversion.

**EDIT 3:**

Also setting the `DocumentInformation` in pre/post convert events don't seem to get it working.

```
converter.PrepareRenderPdfPageEvent += (eventParams) =>
{
    converter.PdfDocumentOptions.DocumentObject.DocumentInformation.Author = "Mike de Klerk";
    converter.PdfDocumentOptions.DocumentObject.DocumentInformation.Title = "PDF/A-1b Test";
    converter.PdfDocumentOptions.DocumentObject.DocumentInformation.Subject = "Testing generation of PDF/A-1b compliant file by EVOPDF library.";
    converter.PdfDocumentOptions.DocumentObject.DocumentInformation.Keywords = "HTML, PDF, Converter, PDF/A-1b. compliance";
    converter.PdfDocumentOptions.DocumentObject.DocumentInformation.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
};
converter.AfterRenderPdfPageEvent += (eventParams) =>
{
    eventParams.Page.Document.DocumentInformation.Author = "Mike de Klerk";
    eventParams.Page.Document.DocumentInformation.Title = "PDF/A-1b Test";
    eventParams.Page.Document.DocumentInformation.Subject = "Testing generation of PDF/A-1b compliant file by EVOPDF library.";
    eventParams.Page.Document.DocumentInformation.Keywords = "HTML, PDF, Converter, PDF/A-1b. compliance";
    eventParams.Page.Document.DocumentInformation.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
};
converter.ConvertHtmlFileToStream(pContentHtmlFile, pOutputStream);
```

**EDIT 4:**

Not even working when converting to a `Document` object first, setting the `DocumentInformation` then, and write the `Document` to the output stream. I feel I am running out of possible workarounds here...

```
        var documentObject = converter.ConvertHtmlFileToPdfDocumentObject(pContentHtmlFile);
        documentObject.DocumentInformation.Author = "Mike de Klerk";
        documentObject.DocumentInformation.Title = "PDF/A-1b Test";
        documentObject.DocumentInformation.Subject = "Testing generation of PDF/A-1b compliant file by EVOPDF library.";
        documentObject.DocumentInformation.Keywords = "HTML, PDF, Converter, PDF/A-1b. compliance";
        documentObject.DocumentInformation.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        documentObject.Save(pOutputStream);
```

**EDIT 5:**

I assumed that when one does `documentObject.DocumentInformation.Author = "Value";`, and it has a setter, it is actually set. but it isn't. Hence, it doesn't matter where I am trying to set these values. They just aren't remembered. This must be a bug. Why is there even a `EvoPdf.DocumentInfo` and a `EvoPdf.PdfDocumentInfo` class? One uses `AuthorName`, and the other `Author`. And more of these differences.

Comment: @EvoPdfHelpDesk Help me please :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the producer of the PDF documents generated by EVO HTML to PDF Converter. This property is read only.

Comment: I've written it successfully to a PDF using `EvoPdf.Document`. But using `EvoPdf.HtmlToPdfConverter` it simply doesn't work. The property has a public setter. How can you say it is read-only?

Comment: And what about the rest of the properties that don't get written to file?

Comment: I could set the author for example with htmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentInfo.AuthorName = "author" . But the Producer property is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Meta data, like author, title, etc. should be written to XMP stream in a PDF that is PDF/A-1b compliant. [See XMP Metadata in PDF/A](http://www.pdfa.org/2009/06/xmp-metadata-in-pdfa-%E2%80%93-metadata-and-the-xmp-format/)

EvoPdf writes meta data to a stream that is not a XMP stream. Therefore, generating a PDf/A-1b compliant file, and adding (non-XMP stream) meta data would result in a file that doesn't comply with PDF/A-1b. So the meta data simply isn't written, to keep the file compliant.

There is a [Adobe XMP Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) that could help you achieve adding meta data to a PDF/A-1b compliant file generated with EvoPdf. But I don't know if it is possible when the file is signed and/or password protected during the generation with EvoPdf.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are creating PDF/A document. This standard does not allow setting an author name.

Comment: This isn't true, meta data is supported in a PDF/A-1b file. But is has to be written to a XMP stream. http://www.pdfa.org/2009/06/xmp-metadata-in-pdfa-%E2%80%93-metadata-and-the-xmp-format/